# Choose different value from strings.xml

Tags: javascript, android-studio

inside my strings.xml i have the following.

```
<string name="alphabet">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</string>
<string name="alphabet_numbers">123456789</string>
```

and i am getting the value of alphabet with my code bellow:
String alphabet = getResources().getString(R.string.alphabet);

I need to get the alphabet_number with if statement but it doesn't work

```
String mychoice = "yes";

if (mychoice.equals(mychoice)){
String alphabet = getResources().getString(R.string.alphabet);
}else{
String alphabet = getResources().getString(R.string.alphabet_numbers);
}
```

It doesn't return the String alphabet. I need to get the string alphabet to use it into my MainActivity class,

Comment: There is a contradiction between `I need to get the alphabet_number with if statement but it doesn't work` and `It doesn't return the String alphabet. ` Can you explain what exactly your requirement is ?

Answer (score 0):

nothing wrong with string resources. you should define returning variable outside if statement.

```
public String returnAlphabet(){
String mychoice = "yes";
String alphabet = null;//define string here
if (mychoice.equals(mychoice)){
alphabet = getResources().getString(R.string.alphabet);
}else{
alphabet = getResources().getString(R.string.alphabet_numbers);
}

return alphabet;
}
```

Comment: Good refactoring suggestion. But as per the logic this will never return value of `alphabet_numbers`. Let's see if author has some other thoughts on the logic.